# Add animation to final square in animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I have this animation in HTML/CSS. The final square in the animation is in green, i'm trying to make it so that each time the green square show up prior to the last time the animation looped. Because in its current state it always shows up at the last square!

HTML:

```
<div class="loader">
  <div class="square" ></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square last"></div>
  <div class="square clear"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square last"></div>
  <div class="square clear"></div>
  <div class="square "></div>
  <div class="square last"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -10px;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50.9% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  55.9% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -10px;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50.9% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  55.9% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -10px;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50.9% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  55.9% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
body {
  background: #1fbeca;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -27.5px;
  margin-top: -27.5px;
}

.square {
  background: white;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  float: left;
  top: -10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s infinite;
}

.enter {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.8s;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
}

.square:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.1s;
  animation-delay: 2.1s;
}

.square:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.4s;
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
  background: #fdc96f;
}

.square:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.square:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.2s;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.square:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.square:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.square:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Here's a link: https://codepen.io/dghez/pen/Czuqn

Answer (score 0):

To have the colored square shift position every time the 'enter' animation is run, create a new animation that is 9 times the length of the 'enter' animation.

The reason for this length is that each of the 9 squares needs to be animated for one full run of the 'enter' animation.

**9 squares x 6s = 54s**.

For 1/9 of this animation (roughly 11%), we change the square's color.

```
@keyframes squarecolor {
  0%, 11.1%   { 
    background-color: #fdc96f;
  }
  11.2%, 100%   { 
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Then, apply this animation to every square, just like the 'enter' animation. Here though, each square should be progressively delayed in increments of 6s.

Here's a [link to an updated version of your Codepen](https://codepen.io/dylanstark/pen/aVbRJb).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the affect by using a 2nd animation that changes a square at a time to yellow for one entire loop of the animation.

The 2nd animation loops after the 1st animation has run for all 9 squares (6s * 9 = 54s), and each square is delayed to some interval of 6s to line up with the corresponding loop where it should be yellow.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -10px;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50.9% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  55.9% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -10px;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50.9% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
  }
  55.9% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0% {
    background: #fdc96f;
  }
  11.11% {  /* one 6s frame in a 54s animation (6/54 = .1111) */
    background: #fdc96f;
  }
  11.12% {
    background: white;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
  }
}
@keyframes change {
  0% {
    background: #fdc96f;
  }
  11.11% {
    background: #fdc96f;
  }
  11.12% {
    background: white;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
  }
}
body {
  background: #1fbeca;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -27.5px;
  margin-top: -27.5px;
}

.square {
  background: white;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  float: left;
  top: -10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.enter {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s 1.8s infinite, change 54s 12s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s 1.8s infinite, change 54s 12s infinite;
}

.square:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s 2.1s infinite, change 54s 6s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s 2.1s infinite, change 54s 6s infinite;
}

.square:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s 2.4s infinite, change 54s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s 2.4s infinite, change 54s infinite;
}

.square:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s 0.9s infinite, change 54s 30s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s 0.9s infinite, change 54s 30s infinite;
}

.square:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s 1.2s infinite, change 54s 24s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s 1.2s infinite, change 54s 24s infinite;
}

.square:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s 1.5s infinite, change 54s 18s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s 1.5s infinite, change 54s 18s infinite;
}

.square:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s infinite, change 54s 48s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s infinite, change 54s 48s infinite;
}

.square:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s 0.3s infinite, change 54s 42s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s 0.3s infinite, change 54s 42s infinite;
}

.square:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation: enter 6s 0.6s infinite, change 54s 36s infinite;
  animation: enter 6s 0.6s infinite, change 54s 36s infinite;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square last"></div>
  <div class="square clear"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square last"></div>
  <div class="square clear"></div>
  <div class="square "></div>
  <div class="square last"></div>
</div>
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/straker/pen/mqdzMw